# Laravel - Insert array of objects to the database

Tags: php, laravel

I have this **variable** which I want to insert to the database. Basically I want to insert array of objects:

```
$data['matching_competitors'] = [
    [
        'id_project'            =>  $id_project, 
        'id_product'            =>  $product_id, 
        'link'                  =>  $link, 
        'id_product_competitor' =>  $id_competitor, 
        'link_competitor'       =>  ''
    ], 
    [
        'id_project'            =>  $id_project, 
        'id_product'            =>  $product_id, 
        'link'                  =>  $link, 
        'id_product_competitor' =>  $id_competitor, 
        'link_competitor'       =>  ''
    ], 
    
];

$insert_matching = DB::connection( $db_name )
                ->table( $db_name . '.product_matching')
                ->insert( $data );
```

but I got an error:

> "Array to string conversion"

Comment: Your best bet is encoding it to JSON, saving it, and upon retrieval decoding it again. Or create a relation for this?

Comment: Do you mean this `$data = json_encode($data);`

Comment: Is each array a new row? If so, you have one too many array levels. Assign that array to `$data` instead of `$data['matching_competitors']`

Comment: Is that a typo ? `->insert( $data['matching_competitors'] );`

Comment: @aynber You are correct, thats' what I need :)